# Why keyword.kwlist doesn't contain 'async' and 'await'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyword

I have Python3.6 and functions like `async def foo(): pass` works perfectly, but I have this output:

```
$ python
Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17) 
>>> import keyword
>>> 'async' in keyword.kwlist
False
>>> 'await' in keyword.kwlist
False
```

Whats wrong with my Python or with its module `keyword`?

Comment: Both have been [added](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/ac317700ce7439e38a8b420218d9a5035bba92ed#diff-50828dd8952e32957f9b06765be3cf83) to the keyword list in Python 3.7.

Comment: Looks like it is only supported since 3.7 in the keyword lib: https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/1669

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with your python installation, it's just version 3.6.

`async` and `await` are only proper keywords since [Python 3.7](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/ac317700ce7439e38a8b420218d9a5035bba92ed), as planned in [PEP 492](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#deprecation-plans).